# Stopping video in viewWillAppear:(bool)animated method

Tags: iphone

In my `viewWillAppear:(bool)animated` method I want to stop video playing. How can I do this? I am new I don't know much.
I am playing a video on this screen. I have a tab which shows table view. When I click on the tab the table view is shown but video is playing in background: we can hear the music.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MPMoviePlayerController, call `-pause` on that object.

Comment: thanks for your answer i am using [indexViewCont.videoPlayer Pause];

Comment: [indexViewCont.videoPlayer stop];

Comment: [indexViewCont.videoPlayer autorelease]; also but it does not stops we can hear the music in background.